# A cartoon with small boys and their toy cars

Tags: story-identification, anime

I just remembered some story.
At first the 2 players need to collect the points by using cars in circular track and next they have to fight with the cars at last who is having more points they will win this is theme of that cartoon.

At starting villain name Asura and his car have special power he car can absorb other player point.

At first Asura will defeat our hero and he will kill him.

But our hero soul with enter into a bat like creature.
That hero car and that bat will found by a small kid.
From then onwards that bat will guide the kid how to play the game.
For that's they have some unique card to transform the car.

Then that kid will defeat all the local player and make a team and enter into tournament and he will defeat Asura and Asura car will kill the Asura.

This the story
Can anyone help me out by telling its name

**Note : it's not scan2go**

I used to watch this in chutti tv channel when I was kid.
I was 2k kid.
So help me out from this.

Comment: *Future GPX Cyber Formula* popped up as a suggestion, bit no match on plot details.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Beompeoking Jaepeo](https://myanimelist.net/anime/19547/Beompeoking_Jaepeo)***, AKA *Bumper King Zapper* (2004)...?

> Bumper King Zapper is a 3D animation series about bumper car battles of the future.

I'm not familiar with this series myself, and can't find much information about the plot online. Some episodes have been uploaded to YouTube, but the audio is in Korean with no subtitles, and YouTube's auto-generated subtitles aren't much help. Judging by what's shown visually, though, it seems to broadly match your description.

The first episode begins in a large arena, where two competitors named Asura and Zapper -- their names are shown on-screen at around the 0:40 mark in the video below -- are driving battle vehicles around circular tracks and collecting icons of some sort. (These aren't toy cars, incidentally; the drivers are actually in them.) The two cars then face off in a head-to-head battle, and at one point, Asura projects ethereal tendrils that latch onto Zapper through his car. Asura ultimately wins the battle and Zapper's car explodes.

The scene then cuts to a young boy, who suddenly wakes up in his bedroom, apparently having dreamed all this.

Later in the episode, the boy meets up with some other kids, one of whom has a remote-controlled car.

Later still, the boy is in what looks like a junkyard, accompanied by a small yellow creature with purple, batwing-like ears. While looking around, the boy notices a small car that looks like the one Zapper was driving in the opening scene, and after picking it up, turns around to see Zapper standing a few feet away from him.

They talk for a bit, before the boy notices that Zapper is intangible and starts running away in fear. Zapper then takes on a more spectral appearance and telekinetically moves large objects in front of the boy, blocking his exit. Zapper has the boy cornered, and lunges towards him, but then the small yellow creature gets in the way, and Zapper ends up inside it, apparently possessing it.

The episode ends there, but that seems pretty close to your description.